# What is the most optimsed way to update locally stored table data in react redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a CRM project I'm storing leads(there are 1000+ leads, I'm getting 10 at a time for pagination) that I get from an api in localStorage. On second load I want to use the local storage to show stored data immediately and update the store with new leads if any new leads are available in the api. To me this seems like he best UX, but I'm unsure about how to go about this.

Also whenever I get new data I don't want to re render the whole page, just render in the new leads.

How do I achieve this?

TL DR: How n when to update localStorage data(which came from an api) that I have persisted with redux persist efficiently with new items that might be available in the api?

Comment: I don't understand your question. This is what React and Redux are exactly designed for. What is exactly the problem ?

Comment: TL DR: How n when to update localStorage data(which came from an api) that I have persisted with redux persist efficiently with new items that might be available in the api?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can check this up. 
http://rationalappdev.com/storing-data-from-api-with-redux-in-react-native-apps/